# Trigger countup on div scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to code a ***count-up*** that would be triggered when a specific `div` is visible on the screen.

I've been going from forum to forum, but none of the examples I used seems to work for me.

It only seems to trigger it correctly if the page is refreshed while the `div` is visible, otherwise the ***count-up*** doesn't seem to activate.

Could anyone help please? Thank you all in advance.

HTML:

```
<section id="facts_section" style="background:#fff;">
  <h1 class="main-title">fun facts about us</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="columns large-3 medium-3">
      <h2 class="count">8</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="columns large-3 medium-3">
      <h2 class="count">15</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="columns large-3 medium-3">
      <h2 class="count">80</h2><span class="percent">&#37;</span>
    </div>

    <div class="columns large-3 medium-3">
      <h2 class="count">5</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**jQuery:**

```
//COUNTUP & MAP/HERO TOGGLE
$times = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var hT = $('#facts_section').offset().top,
      hH = $('#facts_section').outerHeight(),
      wH = $(window).height(),
      wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log((hT - wH), wS);
  if (wS > (hT + hH - wH) && $times == 0) {
    $('.count').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
      });
    });
    $times++;
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by count-up?

Comment: Hi Geoman Yabes, and thank you for your attention. Sorry for no making it too clear, but what I meant was having several numbers going from 0 to a finite value as you hover a specific div (here, their parent container).

Comment: Got a jsFiddle?

Comment: No sorry, never used it unfortunately

Comment: can you include your html?

Comment: The HTML code is now included